# Modal dialog Azure Devops flickering

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I have developed a modal pop up window by using the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/using-host-dialog?view=azure-devops and provided option to open the pop up under Actions option. When pop opens it keeps on opening multiple pages continuously. Is there any solution to stop it and open only one instance of the window?

```
dialogService.openDialog(contributionId, dialogOptions).then(function(dialog){}
```

The above is the code to call the pop window.
[image]

contribution:

```
 "contributions": [
        {
            "id": "registration-form",
            "type": "ms.vss-web.action",
            "description": "The content to be displayed in the dialog",
            "targets": ["ms.vss-work-web.work-item-context-menu"],
            "properties": {
                "text": "ValidateDialog",
                "title": "ValidateDialog",
                "toolbarText": "ValidateDialog",
                "uri": "registration-form.html"           
            }
        }
    ],
    "scopes": [
        "vso.work"
    ],
    "files": [       
        {
            "path": "register_main.js",
            "addressable": true
        },
        {
            "path": "register-form.html",
            "addressable": true
        },
        {
            "path": "node_modules/vss-web-extension-sdk/lib/VSS.SDK.min.js",
            "addressable": true            
        }
    ]
```

I have use following option to call the dialog:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/using-host-dialog?view=azure-devops#showing-the-dialog-advanced

created html file with registration-form.html :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/using-host-dialog?view=azure-devops#dialog-contents

Comment: Hi, Do you mind sharing your detail code here? We need check it and locate the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT thank you for the response. I have updated my question added details, let me know if anything required.